# Trouble with deleting my blog posts using the UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, blogs

I am very new to Ruby on Rails so apologies, as this may be a silly question to post here.

I have made a blog (using generate scaffold). I have a few pages to interact and edit blog posts, starting with a main page which displays all blog posts ("index"), an area to view a specific blog post ("show"), and area to edit a blog post ("edit"), and an area to create a new blog post ("new").
I've also created comments (again using generate scaffold) to be applied to relevant blog posts. Comments, and a partial form for comments appears on the "show" page.

I have been working away on the whole thing to get it working nicely, but have recently realised that delete buttons that I had on the "index" page aren't working. Instead of prompting confirmation for the delete, I'm simply taken to the "show" of the relevant post.

Here is a snippet of the index "index" page:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td><%= post.title %></td>
<td><%= post.content %></td>
<td><%= image_tag "work/thumbnails/#{post.image}", :alt => '' %></td>
<td><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago (<%= post.created_at %>)</td>
<td class="zero-out"><%= link_to 'Show', post, :class => "submit-button" %></td>
<td class="zero-out"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => "submit-button" %></td>
<td class="zero-out"><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => "submit-button" %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

And here is the snippet of code from the posts_controller relevant to the delete:

```
def destroy
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@post.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
  format.json { head :ok }
end
end
```

I have also found that the remove comment buttons (on the "show" page alongside each comment) have stopped working with an error message:

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController

For reference the code for the "remove comment" button is:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove Comment', [comment.post, comment],
    :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
    :method => :delete %>
```

And the snippet of code in the comments_controller is:

```
def destroy
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
@comment.destroy
redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

I lack the full knowledge of how RoR works, and how these files interact with each other fully to troubleshoot the problem, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What does your config/routes.rb look like?

Comment: Iam assuming you have followed this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html . Follow all the steps properly or post code here so we can get a better picture

Comment: There's no mention in my routes.rb of anything to do with the blog. This is for the public view of my website.

And yes I followed this tutorial in part and followed it correctly... something has obviously changed since I stopped using it, but I would preferably like t know why I am coming up with this error so that I can proceed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem - I had customised the links to stylesheets, javascript files etc and in doing this I had left out links to the javascript files for posts and comments created by the scaffold.

After including links to these files everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

First you miss the arrow in the destroy link method call
Correct it to this.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => "submit-button" %>
```

Second you don't have to find the post of a comment to delete it simply do this.

If you want to be redirected back to the post, you do it in the controller

```
<%= link_to 'Remove comment', comment, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

in the comment_controller

```
def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @post = @comment.post
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid none of these worked.

It might be useful to mention that comments are related to posts, so I'm guessing this is why there was post.comment instead of just comment...

Comment: Thats to bad! I have to see more of your code. Put in the complete post index and show view

Comment: I have edited my message above to contain the code within the "index" page that contains the delete button. What else do you need? I must ask what is the important of posting the "show" page code?... ideally, this process shouldn't even involve the "show" page.